# i18next datetime formatting not working in expo project

Tags: internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

My i18.js file (imported in App.js)
[See EDIT below]

My en.json file

```
{
  home: {
    "time": "{{stime, datetime}} to {{etime, datetime}}",
  }
}
```

Translation code in the component

```
const i18timeFormat = { hour: "numeric", minute: "numeric", hour12: true };
return (
    <Text>
      t("home.time",
        {{
          stime: starttime,
          etime: endtime,
          formatParams: { stime: i18timeFormat, etime: i18timeFormat },
        }}
      )
    </Text>
  );
```

Expected output

```
8:30 am to 10:30 am
```

Actual output

```
Wed Apr 13 2022 08:30:12 GMT+0530 (IST) to Wed Apr 13 2022 10:30:12 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

I've also tried the [official example.](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting#datetime) Even it doesn't format. Anything I can try to fix it?

EDIT:
I've added the following packages to polyfill intl datetime and relative time.

```
"@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat": "^5.0.1",
"@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales": "^1.9.2",
"@formatjs/intl-locale": "^2.4.47",
"@formatjs/intl-numberformat": "^7.4.3",
"@formatjs/intl-pluralrules": "^4.3.3",
"@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat": "^10.0.1",
```

i18.js file

```
import "@formatjs/intl-getcanonicallocales/polyfill";
import "@formatjs/intl-locale/polyfill-force";
import "@formatjs/intl-numberformat/polyfill-force";
import "@formatjs/intl-pluralrules/polyfill-force";

import "@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/polyfill-force";
import "@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/locale-data/en";
import "@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/add-all-tz"; // Add ALL tz data

import "@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/polyfill-force";
import "@formatjs/intl-relativetimeformat/locale-data/en";

import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import * as Localization from "expo-localization";

import en from "./i18n/en.json";

const resources = {
  en: { translation: en }
};

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
  resources,
  lng: "en",
  fallbackLng: "en",
});

export default i18n;
```

EDIT 2:
The warning after debug is set to true.

```
Missing locale data for 
at node_modules/@formatjs/intl-localematcher/abstract/utils.js:8:14 in invariant
at node_modules/@formatjs/intl-localematcher/abstract/ResolveLocale.js:25:8 in ResolveLocale
at node_modules/@formatjs/ecma402-abstract/NumberFormat/InitializeNumberFormat.js:31:12 in InitializeNumberFormat
at node_modules/@formatjs/intl-numberformat/src/core.js:37:4 in exports.NumberFormat
at node_modules/@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/src/abstract/FormatDateTimePattern.js:51:13 in FormatDateTimePattern
at node_modules/@formatjs/intl-datetimeformat/src/abstract/FormatDateTime.js:11:16 in FormatDateTime
at node_modules/i18next/dist/cjs/i18next.js:1800:24 in formats.reduce$argument_0
at node_modules/i18next/dist/cjs/i18next.js:1789:19 in format
at node_modules/i18next/dist/cjs/i18next.js:1581:30 in todos.forEach$argument_0
at node_modules/i18next/dist/cjs/i18next.js:1576:6 in interpolate
at node_modules/i18next/dist/cjs/i18next.js:843:14 in extendTranslation
at node_modules/i18next/dist/cjs/i18next.js:806:14 in translate
at src/components/gate/timeBlock/index.js:74:10 in TimeBlock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with the new plural rules: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/faq#why-are-my-plural-keys-not-working

You may also use other polyfills for the in-built formats: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/formatting

Comment: Did that. Added 'intl-pluralrules' package and imported it into i18n.js. It still doesn't work. Anything else I can try?

Comment: You probably need the polyfill for Intl.DateTimeFormat  instead

Comment: I've tried adding packages to polyfill (edit in the post above). I still can't fix the issue though.

Comment: Is there any warning in the developer console if you set debug to true?

Comment: Yes. Added it in the post above. The warning looks incomplete. There's nothing after the "for" in the 1st line. Sorry for bugging you with my bug ‍♂️

Comment: This may help: https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/issues/2054#issuecomment-688008614

Comment: Works! I wrote "import "@formatjs/intl-numberformat/locale-data/en";" and it fixed it. Thank you so much!